# A word for giving but not receiving

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that that describes how someone might be giving and the other person is just taking and not giving nothing back

Comment: A one-sided relationship?

Comment: Can you provide some context, and an example sentence in which you would use this word?

Comment: Without an example sentence, there's absolutely no way to tell. I don't even know if you want us to describe the giver, the taker or the event.

Answer (score 1):

I think your word is: unrequited.

It means doing something without condition. Not completely ensuring your request but I think if you use this word, you won't encounter any problems.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Your answer, no matter how good, needs a citation as to the source (dictionary, etc).

Comment: Annoyingly, it’s a good fit, but the definition here is wrong :o)

Answer (score 1):

@FumbleFingers is spot-on with ***one-sided*** if you want to describe the whole situation, the relationship, or its dynamic.

It *might* be you want ***altruistic*** ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/altruistic)), or simply ***unconditional*** ([*Ibid.*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unconditional)), to describe the behaviour of the giver.

Both of these suggest a lack of *expectation*. If you were implying a degree of abuse in the situation¹, they would shift their meaning slightly (suggesting *naïveté*), but would not be inappropriate.

¹ A common relationship situation is *parenthood*, where it’s expected to be fairly one-sided, and *unconditional* (love) is the norm.

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for is "reciprocity". Verb form: "reciprocate".

verb (used with object), reciprocated, reciprocating.

1. to give, feel, etc., in return. 

   source: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reciprocate

This word is specifically the act of giving *in return*, which you mention. In your example, reciprocity would me missing.

Comment: I think *the word* should be *unreciprocated*. It's a good answer though, and kudos for including the source.